# Java display contents of array from last user input to first user input

Tags: java, arrays

I'm wondering how to display the contents of an array from the last user input to the first user input. For example, if the user input 67 12, I would want to display 12 67, or 56 12 45 23, I would want 23 45 12 56. Unfortunately googling this and searching here only gets me results on descending order which I already have written in another part of my code. Thank you for any help, this is my current code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Array{
  public static void main(String args[]){
      int[] a=new int[2];
      int[] b=new int[a.length];
      Integer[]c = new Integer[a.length];

      Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Please enter two numbers:");
      for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
          a[j]=input.nextInt();
       }

      System.arraycopy(a,0, b, 0, a.length);

      for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
          c[i] = new Integer(a[i]);
      }


      Arrays.sort(a);

      int i;

      System.out.println("Last to First:");

      //Display contents of array 'a' from last user input to first user input.

      System.out.println("Ascending order:");

      for(i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
      }

      Arrays.sort(c, Collections.reverseOrder());

      System.out.println("Descending order:");

      for(i=0; i < c.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(c[i]);
      }

  }
```

}

Comment: For the printing loop, put[ i=c.length-1;i>=0;i--]

Comment: you just want to print the Array in reverse order right? why dont you loop in backward manner?

Answer (score 1):

```
if your array is like this : 
arr[0] = 56
arr[1] = 12
arr[2] = 45
arr[3] = 23
```

get the length and count your loop decremented

```
for(int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
     System.out.println(arr[i]);
   }
```

Comment: It should be arr.length-1. Because array positions start from 0.

Comment: Ahh my bad.. i forgot.. :)

Comment: This worked perfectly using the -1. Thank you both very much for your help!

Comment: @lbreedlove If you have got an answer to the question, then please mark the answer as the correct one.